# Algorithm to assort properties

Tags: algorithms

Pls, bear with me, I have no better way to explain this simply.

Here is the data I have:

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ propA ║ propB ║ propC ║ quantity ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║ 1  ║ 1     ║ 2     ║ 3     ║ 1        ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║ 2  ║ 4     ║ 1     ║ 2     ║ 1        ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║ 3  ║ 5     ║ 4     ║ 1     ║ 2        ║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

Sum of all props:

```
sum  = prop * quantity
sum propA = 1*1 + 4*1 + 5*2 = 15
sum propB = 2*1 + 1*1 + 4*2 = 11
sum propC = 3*1 + 2*1 + 1*2 = 7
```

I can only change **quantity**. I need to get the props to these **goals**:

```
propA = 22
propB = 17
propC = 22
```

The matching quantities are 5, 3 and 1:

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ propA ║ propB ║ propC ║ quantity ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║ 1  ║ 1     ║ 2     ║ 3     ║ 5        ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║ 2  ║ 4     ║ 1     ║ 2     ║ 3        ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║ 3  ║ 5     ║ 4     ║ 1     ║ 1        ║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩══════════╝

sum propA = 1*5 + 4*3 + 5*1 = 22
sum propB = 2*5 + 1*3 + 4*1 = 17
sum propC = 3*5 + 2*3 + 1*1 = 22
```

Is there an algorithm, that can efficiently figure out the **quantity** needed to meet the **goal**?
It's ok if result will be approximate, deviating from the goal for up to 10%.
The real data has ~30 columns (props) and ~100 rows. All numbers are always positive integers.

It would be absolutely terrific, if this algorithm would also allow to set thresholds, like row with id 2 should not have **quantity** be below 3.

Comment: Are you familiar with the optimization technique called linear programming?

Comment: nope, reading about linear programming on wikipedia right now

Comment: And are you more interested in understanding and applying the algorithm yourself, or just finding a tool that will do this?

Comment: I need to program this in my app. If the tool is an open-source library and can do the job perfectly well, then I need that tool. Otherwise - I need to figure out how to write such algorithm.

Comment: Writing it yourself would probably be laborious; it's not conceptually difficult, but just a lot of work. Try searching for "open-source simplex algorithm".